# Will skipping nonce enchance mining performance given there's more resourceful miner

Tags: mining-theory, nonce

As most miner program start with 0 nonce and increment from there, given there are many resourceful miners who will also compete for the same desirable nonce:

Everyone is mining at [0 ~ LARGE_RANGE] (lower range)

I mine at [LARGE_RANGE + 1 ~ MAX_RANGE] (upper range)

Scenario 1: Other people found the desirable nonce at the lower range, they do it way quicker than I do even if I were to mine on the same range.

Scenario 2: The desirable nonce is at my range and I found it first(before others found it since I skipped the lower range)

Is this a possible way to improve my mining performance?

Comment: Do you think that large mining operations have every individual miner start at nonce 0? Of course not. They all start in different places.

Comment: But how are they distributed? Is it random or assigned like a pool, chopping ranges from 0 to N1 and N1 to N2... And if I pick LARGE_RANGE = N_MAX?

Comment: It's up to the mining control software. There is no predetermined plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blocks you try to mine will have *your* block reward address in them. The blocks other people try to mine will have *their* reward address in them. Because the blocks are different, any correct nonces will also be different.

When you mine, you are not competing with other miners in the same search space. Whoever finds their own nonce first wins, but everybody is looking for a different nonce.

Comment: @Geremia Different miners *always* have different transactions, because one of the transactions is the reward transaction to themselves.